# How do I add different data types from text file into an array?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to add these data types from a text file into an array, but am getting out of range memory errors. The text file looks like this:

```
1234,Chris Bobby,9/9/1999,123 Main Street,123-456-7890,5000.00
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
void AddCustomersToArray(Customer *customers, fstream& customersFile) {
string line;
int i = 0;

string Number;
string FullName;
string DOB;
string Address;
string Telephone;
string Balance;

while (getline(customersFile, line)) {
    stringstream ss(line);

    getline(ss, Number, ',');
    customers[i].Number = stoi(Number);
    //cout << customers[i].Number << endl;

    getline(ss, FullName, ',');
    customers[i].FullName = FullName;
    //cout << customers[i].FullName << endl;

    getline(ss, DOB, ',');
    customers[i].DOB = DOB;
    //cout << customers[i].DOB << endl;

    getline(ss, Address, ',');
    customers[i].Address = Address;
    //cout << customers[i].Address << endl;

    getline(ss, Telephone, ',');
    customers[i].Telephone = Telephone;
    //cout << customers[i].Telephone << endl;

    getline(ss, Balance, ',');
    customers[i].Balance = stoi(Balance);
    //cout << customers[i].Balance << endl;

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the calling code? We need to see what you're passing in for `customers`.

Comment: What is the size of your array? How many customers are in that file?

Comment: customers is an array of a customer structure declared in the global scope with a size of 10. As of now, there's 2 customers in the file. This is just a snippet of the overall project, as there's functions later that let the user add and delete customers from the file.

Comment: Maybe your file with only two customers has more than ten lines?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a vector? Then you dynamically increase the needed size like so:

```
void AddCustomersToVector(std::vector<Customer>& customers, fstream& customersFile)
{
    //...
    while (getline(customerFile, line)) {
        Customer& newCustomer = customers.emplace_back();
        //...
        newCustomer.FullName = FullName;
        //...
    }
}
```

The "emplace_back()" call on the vector will construct a "Customer" at the end of your vector with no arguments and hand over the address (as a reference) of this very "Customer".
So the call `newCustomer.FullName = FullName`would overwrite the member "FullName" of the "Customer" just created.

Comment: Okay, yeah a vector would make more sense, I'm just not familiar with them as we're not taught them in my university. I'm not understanding the     "Customer& newCustomer = customers.emplace_back();" however.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Where I have:

```
getline(ss, Balance, ',');
customers[i].Balance = stoi(Balance);
```

I have to convert it to a double, not an integer. So, changing it to this fixed it:

```
getline(ss, Balance, ',');
customers[i].Balance = stod(Balance);
```